# Unexplained padding in unordered list within table

Tags: html, css

I'm currently putting together a little start page but I'm having trouble with some unexplained padding issues in a list. Here is the full code so far:

```html
<html>
  <body>
<style type="text/css">

  html, * {
   font-family: Hermit, monospace;
   color: #eceff1;font-size: 12px;
   height: 100%;
  }

  body {
   font-size: 12px;

   background: #222c32;
   color: #222c32;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  li {
   margin-left: 15px;
  }

  h1 {
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #222c32;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  p {
   color: #222c32;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  a {
   color: #222c32;
   text-decoration: none;
  }

  .theme {
   outline: 3px solid black;
   background: white;
   color: black;
  }

  .container {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .cent {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .content {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 800px;
   height: 500px;
  }

  .links {
   margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
   width: 555px;
   height: 445px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
  }

  .picture1 {
   color: black;
   margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
   width: 215px;
   height: 215px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   background: url("dmc.jpg")
  }

  .picture2 {
   margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
   width: 215px;
   height: 215px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   background: url("kaneda.jpg")
  }

  .gsearch {
   margin: 5px 5px 10px 10px;
   width: 555px;
   height: 25px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
  }

  .ysearch {
   margin: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
   width: 215px;
   height: 25px;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
  }

  .header {
   margin-top: 150px;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
  }

  .linktext {
   margin-left: 10px;
   text-align: center;
  }

 </style>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="cent">
       <div class="content">
        <div class="links theme">
         <div class="header">
          <h1>kakarotten</h1>
          <table>
           <tr>
            <th>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/asp/">/asp/</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/mu/">/mu/</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/tg/">/tg/</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/w/">/w/</a></li>
             </ul>
            </th>
            <th>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/unixporn/">unxprn</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/vinyl">vinyl</a></li>
             </ul>
            </th>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="picture1 theme"></div>
        <div class="picture2 theme"></div>
        <div class="gsearch theme"></div>
        <div class="ysearch theme"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The second list along seems to be spacing itself out, I'm just wondering why.

Comment: I'm 100% sure this should not be in a `<table>` to begin with. Refactor your code, is my best advice.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie how would i go about placing 3 or 4 unordered lists next to each other in the best fashion? I was using a table for convenience but I understand it's bad practice.

Comment: Take a look at the example I gave using flexbox.  This gives a straightforward approach without having to use float or inline-block.  For more information on flexbox see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @junkfoodjunkie.  But it's because of this CSS rule

```
html, * {
    font-family: Hermit, monospace;
    color: #eceff1;font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is setting everything to be 100% of it's container's height.

Also, you could use `display:inline-block;` on each `<ul>` to place them next to each other instead of using a `table`.

Comment: getting rid of the `height` rule fixed it! Thanks so much, now I know for next time.

Comment: @LouieHenderson It is interesting that it didn't seem to affect your other list though....

Answer (score 2):

I would use flexbox to place unordered lists next to each other.

```css
    html, * {
        font-family: Hermit, monospace;
        color: #eceff1;font-size: 12px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        font-size: 12px;

        background: #222c32;
        color: #222c32;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #222c32;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    p {
        color: #222c32;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    a {
        color: #222c32;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .theme {
        outline: 3px solid black;
        background: white;
        color: black;
    }

    .container {
      display: table;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .cent {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .content {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .links {
        margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
        width: 555px;
        height: 445px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    .picture1 {
        color: black;
        margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
        width: 215px;
        height: 215px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        background: url("dmc.jpg")
    }

    .picture2 {
        margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
        width: 215px;
        height: 215px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        background: url("kaneda.jpg")
    }

    .gsearch {
        margin: 5px 5px 10px 10px;
        width: 555px;
        height: 25px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ysearch {
        margin: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
        width: 215px;
        height: 25px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header {
        margin-top: 150px;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .linktext {
        margin-left: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
.list-group {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
}
.list-group ul {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cent">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="links theme">
                    <div class="header">
                      <h1>kakarotten</h1>
                      <div class="list-group">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/asp/">/asp/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/mu/">/mu/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/tg/">/tg/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/w/">/w/</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/unixporn/">unxprn</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/vinyl">vinyl</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/asp/">/asp/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/mu/">/mu/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/tg/">/tg/</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://boards.4chan.org/w/">/w/</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/unixporn/">unxprn</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/vinyl">vinyl</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="picture1 theme"></div>
                <div class="picture2 theme"></div>
                <div class="gsearch theme"></div>
                <div class="ysearch theme"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure is wrong. You should use th as table header then tr as table row.

Example below:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cent">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="links theme">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h1>kakarotten</h1>
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                                <th>
                                   <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a> </th>
                                   <th>
                                   <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a> </th>
                                   <th>
                                   <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a> </th>
                                   <th>
                                   <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a> </th>
                                   <th>
                                   <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/a/">/a/</a> </th>
                                       </tr>
                               
                                <tr>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                
                                
                                </tr>
                                
                                 <tr>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                <td><a href="https://reddit.com/r/squaredcircle/">sqrdcrcl</a></td>
                                
                                
                                </tr>
                                       
                           
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="picture1 theme"></div>
                <div class="picture2 theme"></div>
                <div class="gsearch theme"></div>
                <div class="ysearch theme"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.
Best of luck

Comment: Table headers should be wrapped in a row.

Comment: And both `<th>`s and `<td>`s should respectively be wrapped in a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>`...